# String values not matching C++

Tags: c++, syntax

Hi generous people of StackExchange,

I'm working with C++ and I've seemed to run into the error of not being able to match two string values properly. I have the code in main:

```
/**
*   Author: Kevin Hill
*   Assignment: Project5
*   Description: VehicleDB
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Vehicle.h"
//#include "Truck.h"
//#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

bool checkLine(string, string);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    string fileName; //This is the file name
     //Vehicle array
    ifstream file; //Instantiate file
    string sLine;
    Vehicle **vehArr;

    //Tell user to enter data
    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    file.open(fileName.c_str());
    if(!file.is_open()){
        cerr << "The file is not there" << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    //Get first line of file to determine size of vehArr    
    for (int i = 0; !file.eof(); ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0){
            getline(file, sLine); 
            break;
        }
    }

    int arrSize = atoi(sLine.c_str());
    vehArr =  new (nothrow) Vehicle*[arrSize];
    string truck = "truck";
    string car = "car";
    while(!file.eof()){
        getline(file, sLine);
        string stuff = sLine;
        checkLine(stuff, car);
    }

    // Test add Truck and Car objects
    // vehArr[0] = new Car(file);
    // vehArr[1] = new Truck();

    string theLine = "";

    // checkLine("one", "one");

    // cout << "Beginning loop" << endl;

    // for (int i = 0; !file.eof(); ++i){
    //  getline(file, theLine);



    //  // if(theLine == "car"){
    //  //  vehArr[i] = new Car(file);
    //  //  i++;
    //  // }
    //  // if (theLine == "truck"){
    //  //  vehArr[i] = new Truck(file);
    //  //  i++;
    //  // }
    //  // if (i == arrSize){
    //  //  break;
    //  // }    
    // }

    return 0;
}

bool checkLine(string one, string two){

    // if (one == two)
    // {
    //  /* code */
    // }



    if (one == two)
    {
        cout << "It's a " << two << endl;
    }
    // cout << one << endl;
    // cout << two << endl;

    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I commented the code out to get rid of all the stuff that's not important for my problem. When I read my file I try to make a match of all the lines that equal car. It should work because I tried having all lines equal themselves and that worked, but having the lines equal `car` alone just didn't work out. I'm now stuck on this one thing.

This is the text file it's reading from:

```
5
car
11111
Ford
Fusion FWD
Red
24999.00
3
AC
795.00
XM
295.00
Leather Seats
495.00
20
28
car
22222
Volvo
V70 FWD
White
42999.00
2
Child Seats
198.00
17" wheels
698.00
14
22
car
33333
Honda
Accord
Silver
19999.00
1
Tinted Windows
175.00
22
31
truck
44444
Freightliner
FLD SD
Red
119999.00
1
Detroit Diesel Series 60
4999.00
10 speed manual
455
truck
55555
Mack
TerraPro Cabover MRU612
White
125000.00
1
Dual Air Brake System
6000.00
8 speed manual
325
```

It's necessary for me to actually complete my assignment, but I can't figure out how fix this. Please help me.

Comment: Note: see this: `while(!file.eof())` ? Now read this: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Then consider how *every* `std::getline()` that you're invoking should be checked in a conditional of some kind.

Comment: Is it intentional for your `checkLine()` function to be returning true all the time, no matter whether or not the strings are equal?

Comment: Now I've run into an even bigger issue. When I have any spaces it thinks I switched my line. How do I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thank WhozCraig and for giving me the answer. There was probably come indexing issue that occured because I used !file.eof() instead of `file >> data`.

So here was the minor code difference:

```
string truck = "truck";
string car = "car";
//Old version
 while(!file.eof()){
    getline(file, sLine);
    string stuff = sLine;
    checkLine(stuff, car);
 }

string data;
while(file >> data){    
// cout << data << endl;
checkLine(data, car);
}
```